# make javascript work on a non submit button in form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that has two divs in it. One is shown normally and one is hidden. The first form has input elements, I have them as required in the html. If the user fills in the first form and presses the button, the first div slides up and the second one `slideDown()`. And when the user presses the button in the second div, it submits the form.

The problem is the javascript that requires the user to fill in all inputs doesn't work on the div that has the inputs, because it's button only `slideup()` the first div and `slideDown()` the second div which has the actual submit button.

If I have the first button as type `submit` it will submit the form without showing the second div and will redirect to the next page immediately.

How can I make the JavaScript work on the first button but submit on the second? I hope I explained all of this in the right way.

```
<form>

  <div id="choosing">

    //form inputs required
    <button type="button" id="show">

  </div> 
  
  <div id="confirmation">

    //irrelevant stuff
    <button type="submit">

  </div>

</form>
```

the javascript

```
<script> 
$('#show').click(function(e) {
    
  $("#choosing").slideUp();
  $("#confirmation").slideDown();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you first want to have the inputs validated in the `#choosing` div before calling `slideUp()` and being able to submit the form?

Comment: yes exactly, i want it to be validated in the #choosing and submitted in the #confirmation

Comment: Then it would make sense if you'd include the inputs that need validations. Then we could see how the validation should be made as it is unfortunately not a "one size fits all" solution. Please edit your question and include any HTML and JS relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

from your question I get that you want is to implement a confirmation step.
Below you can find a simple implementation that can help you out to achieve your goal

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const confirm = document.querySelector('#confirm');
const cancel = document.querySelector('#cancel');
const validation = document.querySelector('.validation');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  validation.classList.add('validation-show');
});


confirm.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  validation.classList.remove('validation-show');
 
  // send your data
  // by serializing the form (e.g new FormData(form));

  
  // reseting form once you have sent your data
  form.reset();
});

cancel.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  validation.classList.remove('validation-show');
});
```

```css
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.two-step-form {
  position: relative;
}

.validation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 
    transform .3s ease-in-out,
    opacity .3s ease-in-out,
    visibility .3s ease-in-out;
  
}

.validation-show {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 100;
  visibility: visible;
}

.validation-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  
}
```

```html
<form class="two-step-form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="validation">
      <div class="validation-content">
        <p>Are you sure?</p>
        <div>
          <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" id="confirm">Confirm</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```